# C# How to Adjust List to Closest Target Amount

Tags: c#

I am having problem. I hope anyone could suggest.

Problem: I had a list of amount and I want to adjust the list closest to the target amount by removing some of the list amount.

List:

```
2
4
7
41
6
2
```

Sum of list item:  `62`

Target: `24`

Comment: please, put some code. what do you tried?

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to achive

Comment: Nothing yet sir.. im just new in c#

Comment: Do you mean summing up selective numbers to get nearest value to the target?

Comment: Attempt your homework first, if you get stuck come back here with a specific problem.

Comment: Yes sir summing up the list.

Comment: Guess i have too :)  thanks sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know what you are doing; please follow the steps given below

**The algorithm used below to do what you want to achieve is not perfect and must be improved but at-least it will get you started.**

1. Create a Console Application using Visual Studio
2. Paste the code given below in your Program.cs file
3. Run the application and follow the instructions

.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace StackOverFlowHelp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the Amounts Separated By space : ");
            var listItems = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the target : ");
            var target = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            List<Int32> numbers = listItems.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
            if (numbers.Count <= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The list must contain at-least 2 numbers");
            }
            else
            {
                var currentSum = numbers.Sum();
                if (currentSum == target)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SUM of List " + string.Join(" ", numbers) + " already matches the target " + target + ". No number has been removed.");
                }
                else if (currentSum < target)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SUM of List " + string.Join(" ", numbers) + " is smaller than the target " + target + ". No number can been removed.");
                }
                else
                {
                    numbers.Sort();
                    var incrementalSum = 0;
                    var qualifiedIndex = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        incrementalSum += numbers[i];
                        if (incrementalSum == target)
                        {
                            /*Remove the numbers after index value*/
                            qualifiedIndex = i + 1;
                        }
                        else if (incrementalSum > target)
                        {
                            /*Remove the numbers from index value*/
                            qualifiedIndex = i;
                        }
                        if (qualifiedIndex > 0)
                        {
                            /*We are ready with our results*/
                            Console.WriteLine("SUM of List " + string.Join(" ", numbers.Take(qualifiedIndex)) + " is closest to the target " + target + ". Following number can been removed: " + string.Join(" ", numbers.Skip(qualifiedIndex).Take(numbers.Count - qualifiedIndex)));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (qualifiedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Could not find any number to remove.");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Exit.....");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: See the Sample Image to have an Idea about how the application works.]

Comment: Wow this is what exactly what i meant. Thanks sir ajay

Comment: Please be advised that you must work on improving the logic to determine the numbers that need to be removed and if you are happy with the code please accept this as an answer.

Comment: Your algorithm will help me a lot sir. this is my sample list i'm talking about https://photos.app.goo.gl/ujmfWxY9qcRiFitt2